# Cant get items from list by Date data type (getting blank page)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have problem to get any data showing up while I'm trying to acces this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/transits/2017-10-22
```

When I get

```
http://localhost:8080/transits
```

Data is showing up:

```
[{"date":"3917-11-21","source_adress":"WASS","destination_adress":"SS","price":450},{"date":"3917-11-21","source_adress":"DASS","destination_adress":"DD","price":450},{"date":"3917-11-21","source_adress":"MASS","destination_adress":"CC","price":450}]
```

Hello guys, im trying to write API using Spring boot. Can u help me whats wrong with my code so i cant get transit from "date"? i added

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

But this didn't help me. Even when I'm tring to enter my json data format which is "3917-11-21" nothing happens. Thanks in advance.
[Program tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKPjA.jpg)

This is my TransportDAO

```
   package com.dariusz.Dao;

    import com.dariusz.Entity.Transport;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    @Repository
    public class TransportDao {

        private static final Map<Integer, Transport> transports = new HashMap<Integer, Transport>() {
           {
                put(1, new Transport("WASS", "SS", 450,new Date(2017,10,22)));
                put(2, new Transport("DASS", "DD", 450,new Date(2017,10,22)));
                put(3, new Transport("MASS", "CC", 450,new Date(2017,10,22)));
            }
        };

        public Collection<Transport> getAllTransports(){
            return this.transports.values();
        }

        public Transport getTransportByDate(Date date){
            return this.transports.get(date);
        }

    }
```

TransportService

```
package com.dariusz.Service;

import com.dariusz.Dao.TransportDao;
import com.dariusz.Entity.Transport;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@Service
public class TransportService {

    @Autowired
    private TransportDao transportDao;

    public Collection<Transport> getAllTransports(){
        return this.transportDao.getAllTransports();
    }

    public Transport getTransportByDate(Date date){
        return this.transportDao.getTransportByDate(date);
    }
}
```

Transport.java

```
package com.dariusz.Entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Transport {


    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
    private String source_adress;
    private String destination_adress;
    private int price;
    public Transport(String source_adress, String destination_adress, int price, Date date) {
        this.source_adress = source_adress;
        this.destination_adress = destination_adress;
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Transport(){}

    public String getSource_adress() {
        return source_adress;
    }

    public void setSource_adress(String source_adress) {
        this.source_adress = source_adress;
    }

    public String getDestination_adress() {
        return destination_adress;
    }

    public void setDestination_adress(String destination_adress) {
        this.destination_adress = destination_adress;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;

    }

}
```

TransportController

```
package com.dariusz.Controller;

import com.dariusz.Entity.Transport;
import com.dariusz.Service.TransportService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@RestController

@RequestMapping("/transits")

public class TransportController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }
    @Autowired
    private TransportService transportService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Transport> getAllTransports(){
        return transportService.getAllTransports();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{date}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Transport getTransportByDate(@PathVariable("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") @RequestParam(required = false) Date date){
        return transportService.getTransportByDate(date);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but...

```
public Transport getTransportByDate(Date date){
      return this.transports.get(date);
}
```

should return the transports with the key `date` from the map `transports`. However, in your case, the key can be `1`, `2` or `3`. I think the problem lie here.

You could put an extended repository with a `extends JpaRepository<Transports, Integer>` (or mongo or whatever is your database) or juste do a

```
public Transport getTransportByDate(Date date){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Transport> entry : this.transport.entrySet()){
                if (date.equals(entry.getValue().getDate()) {
                        return entry.getValue();
                }
        }
}
```

(That's not classy, but the idea is here).

Comment: I tried to change my code as you mentioned but unfortunately it doesn't compile.  (Error:(29, 40) java: for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,com.dariusz.Entity.Transport>

Comment: Mea culpa, it's a map, not a list. Take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map. I've edited my answer, sorry for the mistake !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8(or above), use the newer type/class which is `LocalDate` if date only or `LocalDateTime` if contains time. That is a replacement for the old legacy date-time classes such as java.util.Date, Calendar, & SimpleDateFormat.

```
public class Transport {


    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;

    //code remove for brevity
}
```

Comment: @OleV.V. It's good advice to use LocalDate, but the date format wasn't the reason why i couldn't get data (blank page problem).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, it does. Answer updated. (only data type was updated)